# Pulling Extension from Phone Number

Tags: php, regex

I am looking for a php/regex solution to get the phone extension from the data examples listed below.

```
+49 (0) 1111 807 111 (Ext 1012)
+49 (0) 1111 807 111 (Ext1012)
+49 (0) 1111 807 111 [Ext 1012]
+49 (0) 2222 807 111 <Ext 1012>
+49 (0) 2222 807 111 <Ext1012>
+49 (0) 2222 807 111 <1012>
+49 (0) 2222 807 111 [1012]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Remove the last character from the string, and then grab the last four characters.

Comment: @4castle is 'echo substr($number, -5, -1);' what you mean?

Comment: @Gabriel Yes, already upvoted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
/(\(Ext|(\[|<)(Ext)?)\s*(\d+)(\)|>|])/
```

The first part will capture:

```
$phones = '
+49 (0) 1111 807 111 (Ext 1012)
+49 (0) 1111 807 111 (Ext1012)
+49 (0) 1111 807 111 [Ext 1012]
+49 (0) 2222 807 111 <Ext 1012>
+49 (0) 2222 807 111 <Ext1012>
+49 (0) 2222 807 111 <1012>
+49 (0) 2222 807 111 [1012]
';

preg_match_all('/(\(Ext|(\[|<)(Ext)?)\s*(\d+)(\)|>|])/', $phones, $matches);
```

The `var_dump` of $matches would give you an array and you are interested in the 4th capture group.

```
array(7) {
    [0]=> string(4) "1012"
    [1]=> string(4) "1012"
    [2]=> string(4) "1012"
    [3]=> string(4) "1012"
    [4]=> string(4) "1012"
    [5]=> string(4) "1012"
    [6]=> string(4) "1012"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

echo part of the string from -5 to -1

```
echo substr($number, -5, -1);
```

for '+49 (0) 1111 807 111 (Ext 1012)', it returns '1012'

Comment: There's a ( on the 0 at the start that'd cause issues

Comment: @clearshot66 I'm sorry but i didn't get it, can you please tell me what's the problem again? thanks! i've tested it and it worked ?_?

Comment: +49 (0) 1111 807 111 (Ext 1012) --> The (0) is also a (, and he's trying to get the extension at the end, not the +49, he wants the 1012

Answer (score 2):

Don't need regex if the first set of characters is always the same. Get the length of the string and get the first 21 characters of that (spaces included up to the extension start). Figure out how many positions make up the extension and substring from that.

Example of what I mean:
+49 (0) 1111 807 111 (Ext 1012)
say thats `$string = "+49 (0) 1111 807 111 (Ext 1012)";`

$length = strlen($string) will give you 31.

Remove up to the extension gives you to 20 (position 19 being the space. So anything from 21-30 is the extension.

```
echo $string[21].$string[22].$string[23].....$string[30];
```

or you could use substr and get the ending positions. Use - to go in reverse counting from 1.

```
echo substr($string,-5,-1);
```

Comment: What if the length of the numbers are different?

Comment: If it's a phone number they never will be.   Phone numbers are uniform in those examples.  523 111 1231 for example will always be that format for all phone numbers in that region. The asker is looking for the last grouping so anything past the final digit set

Comment: That's not true at all. Where I live there's 1-888-123-4567 and there's 450-123-4567 which has two different formats and both could have extensions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following *regex (using [positive lookahead / lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html))* to get all the extensions from the phone numbers :

```
(?<=\d{3}\s[\(\[<]).*?(?=\)|\]|>)
```

­

```
input        >>  +49 (0) 1111 807 111 (Ext 1012)
regex search >>  (?<=\d{3}\s[\(\[<]).*?(?=\)|\]|>)
output       >>  Ext 1012
```

see [demo / explanation](https://regex101.com/r/Sq2PEx/1)

**PHP**

```
$re = '/(?<=\d{3}\s[\(\[<]).*?(?=\)|\]|>)/';
$str = '+49 (0) 1111 807 111 (Ext 1012)
        +49 (0) 1111 807 111 (Ext1012)
        +49 (0) 1111 807 111 [Ext 1012]
        +49 (0) 2222 807 111 <Ext 1012>
        +49 (0) 2222 807 111 <Ext1012>
        +49 (0) 2222 807 111 <1012>
        +49 (0) 2222 807 111 [1012]';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```